# PL/SQL help me making this code

Tags: oracle, plsql

Create PL / SQL blocks using cursors to update salary columns on employee tables, from employees working in specific departments inputted via keyboard.
Salaries are raised by the rules:

- If the employee is less than 16 years old, raise the salary 15%
- If the length of employment of employees between 16-20 years, increase salary by 20%
- If the employee is over 20 years old, raise salary 25%

Show employee_id, last_name, old job, new salary, on updated employees table.

Enter value for d_id: 30

```
EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME                  LAMAKERJA     SALARY
----------- ------------------------- ---------- ----------
        119 Colmenares                16.1452239       3000
        118 Himuro                    16.8794705       3120
        116 Baida                     17.7726212       3480
        117 Tobias                    18.1917992       3360
        115 Khoo                      20.3781006       3720
        114 Raphaely                  20.8219362      13200

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Whoever wrote that homework assignment does apparently not understand that it is much more efficient to do this without PL/SQL in a single UPDATE statement. There is no reason to use a cursor for this. This is teaching bad coding style.

Comment: help me to solve this

Comment: The homework assignment may be made that way to show a very simple loop through the records. But as long he do not try anything himself and he learn to say "please" no one will help.

Comment: This also presents a problem in interpreting stated requirements or clearly stating them. 
As stated the problem has 3 criteria but on 2 different things: 1st and 3rd based on age but the 2nd based length of employment. 
What happens when a single employee meets 0 or 2 conditions. 
Examples: A 19 year old with length of employment of 2 years. Meets 0 criteria. Gets 0% raise?
          A 38 year old with length of employment of 18 years. Meets 2 criteria (2nd and 3rd). Gets 20%, or 25%, or 45% raise?
The answer could drastically change the shape of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started: *age* is a common problem so let's suppose that my trivial calculation does the job. Loop through all employees, check conditions you were told and update employee's salary. The final `SELECT` is up to you, completely.

```
   FOR cur_r
      IN (SELECT employee_id, TRUNC ( (SYSDATE - date_of_birth) / 365.25) age
            FROM employees)
   LOOP
      UPDATE employees e
         SET e.salary =
                  e.salary * CASE
                               WHEN age ... THEN ...
                               WHEN age ... THEN ...
                             END
       WHERE e.employee_id = ...
   END LOOP;
```